# Why does Neo have superpowers in the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

I watched the Matrix movies, and the explanation given for Neo flying and having super-strength and telekinesis is that the Matrix isn't real, and it can be hacked/modded. How does Neo have powers in the simulated reality of the Matrix? I don't understand how Neo could do whatever he wants in the Matrix. Plus, his stamina is finite, which doesn't make sense to me since it is a computer simulation. How do Neo's powers work in the matrix in the matrix movies?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you asking for an explanation of powers in the Matrix in real-world terms?  Asking about why a fictional universe doesn't match reality are off-topic; if you want to establish a requirement to upload cracks to exploit the system you have to demonstrate that it worked that way in the movie.

Comment: @DavidW I'm sorry, I strayed off topic there. I edited the question to be more answerable.

Comment: You have pretty much answered your own question. Think of it as a modded Computer game were you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @A.Steer I'm confused though. If the Matrix is such that you can do whatever you want, why can't other people do what Neo can do? And Neo has limits even in the Matrix. He was overwhelmed by the Smith clones, and he can bleed.

Comment: So how come since it is a computer game Neo can bleed, die, get exhausted, and why cant Neo simply snap his finger and make the Smith clones disappear?

Comment: _The body cannot live without the mind...._

Comment: I believe that the people in the Matrix who express superpowers have learned to rewrite bits of the Matrix's programming for their own benefit. None of the characters are physically inside the matrix: their bodies either reside in the machines' energy pods, or in the Nebuchadnezzar's Matrix-access interfaces. Since the Matrix itself is a virtual world, those in the know can shift its parameters in regards to their own persons.

Comment: "*Morpheus: This is a sparring program, similar to the programmed reality of the Matrix. It has the same basic rules, rules like gravity. What you must learn is that these rules are no different that the rules of a computer system. Some of them can be bent. Others can be broken. Understand? Then hit me. If you can…. Good. Adaptation, improvisation. But your weakness is not your technique.*"

Comment: Neo has powers because **the purpose of his birth is to attract people with his powers**. I suspect what you're asking is 'why do the Zionese rebels have powers' but the answer to that one is 'because they don't perceive the Matrix as real, but rather a system that they can subconsciously learn to subvert'

Comment: @Valorum I remember that quote from the first Matrix movie. I just do not understand how people like Neo and Trinity and Morpheus are able to bend and break the rules in universe. It is easy to break a games rules from the outside (modding a game on your computer) but I don't understand how the people in the Matrix mod the "game" while IN the game and how they do it so quickly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Neo teleport at random?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19787/why-doesnt-neo-teleport-at-random)

Answer (score 2):

Neo is The One, and has superhuman abilities due to his connection to the Source. This is explained (poorly) when he meets The Architect. According to [fandom](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/The_Architect#The_Sixth_One):

> One significant anomaly appeared two-thirds into the Matrix's first
> cycle. A human was imbued with control of additional Matrix
> programming, and an instrinsic, metaphysical conceptulisation of the
> Matrix that was derived from the Source.

Comment: I read the Matrix Wiki. I still do not understand how the people in the Matrix can hack it instantly.

Comment: @Lymona - The same way that any skilled speedrunner can use 'hacks' and 'glitches' to gain huge advantages over normies - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1q3TseThXQ

Comment: One of the Animatrix shorts is about an athlete who runs so fast he breaks the matrix a bit and sees the machine world. People are exceeding the parameters of the matrix by pure skill and ability. Just like a real world hacker who can crack a computer network while someone else cannot

Comment: @A.Steer so if different people have different superpowers due to their natural ability, then is it really superpowers?

Comment: There not superpowers at all. They are individuals who are able to break a defined set of rules. It's like the third if Clarke's three laws - "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic", or in this setting superpowers